# ¿Cómo usa la autenticación con huella dactilar en xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, autenticación, huelladigital

me enfrento a la necesidad de autenticar una persona por medio de su huella dactilar en una app con xamarin forms, pero por seguridad Android no permite extraer la huella que escanea el sensor y mi necesidad es enviar esa huella hasta una API para ser comparada con las que tengo en mi BD, ahora sí no es posible hacer eso que me pueden recomendar para poder verificar que sea la persona registrada ?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Revisaste ya [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fingerprint-authentication/)?

Comment: Si he visto varios ejemplos de la documentación pero lo único que me devuelve el sdk de android en un valor booleano cuando se autentique la persona duela del móvil, pero no puedo obtener la imagen de la huella escaneada...

Comment: Los datos biométricos [no están disponibles](https://source.android.com/docs/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal). Sería un problema serio de seguridad :) _Thus, raw images and processed fingerprint features must not be passed in untrusted memory. All such biometric data needs to be secured within sensor hardware or trusted memory. (Memory inside the TEE is considered as trusted memory; memory outside the TEE is considered untrusted.)_

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Luego editar la pregunta.